# Why VAE loss doesn’t converge to zero?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, autoencoder, loss

I’m using a Variational Autoencoder and this is my implementation for the loss function:

```
class VariationalAutoencoder(nn.Module):
    # ...some functions...

    def gaussian_likelihood(self, x_hat, logscale, x):
        scale = torch.exp(logscale)
        mean = x_hat
        dist = torch.distributions.Normal(mean, scale)
        # measure prob of seeing image under p(x|z)
        log_pxz = dist.log_prob(x)
        return log_pxz.sum(dim=(1, 2, 3))

    def forward(self, input):
        mu, logvar = self.encode(input)
        z = self.reparameterise(mu, logvar)
        return self.decoder(z), mu, logvar, z

    def loss_function(self, x_hat, x, mu, logvar, β=1):
        std = torch.exp(logvar / 2)
        q = torch.distributions.Normal(mu, std)
        z = q.rsample()

        # reconstruction loss
        recon_loss = self.gaussian_likelihood(x_hat, self.log_scale, x)

        # kl
        kl = self.kl_divergence(z, mu, std)

        # elbo
        elbo = (kl - recon_loss)
        elbo = elbo.mean()
        return elbo

    def kl_divergence(self, z, mu, std):
        # --------------------------
        # Monte carlo KL divergence
        # --------------------------
        # 1. define the first two probabilities (in this case Normal for both)
        p = torch.distributions.Normal(torch.zeros_like(mu), torch.ones_like(std))
        q = torch.distributions.Normal(mu, std)

        # 2. get the probabilities from the equation
        log_qzx = q.log_prob(z)
        log_pz = p.log_prob(z)

        # kl
        kl = (log_qzx - log_pz)
        kl = kl.sum(-1)

        return kl
```

I use Sigmoid() function when exiting the decoder. I train the model in this way:

```
for epoch in range(0, epochs + 1):
        if epoch > 0:  # test untrained net first
            model.train()
            train_loss = 0
            loop = tqdm(train_loader)
            optimizer = model.setOptimizer(model)
            for x in loop:
                x = x.to(device)
                x_hat, mu, logvar, features = model(x)
                loss = model.loss_function(x_hat, x, mu, logvar)
                train_loss += loss.item()
                optimizer.zero_grad()
                loss.backward()
                optimizer.step()
                loop.set_postfix(loss=loss)
            train_loss = train_loss /= len(train_loader.dataset)
            print(f'====> Epoch: {epoch} Average loss: {train_loss:.4f}')
```

The loss doesn’t settle at zero but but becomes negative (around -2). If I remove `train_loss = train_loss /= len(train_loader.dataset)`, it’s diverges completely.

How can I make the loss converge to zero?

Answer (score 1):

Loss for VAE can be negative. It has a log-likelihood - which can be negative. There is nothing wrong in that.

Comment: Is it correct to divide by the length of the dataset?

Comment: not sure how its useful, its not even being used for backprop. you are doing bakward on `loss`, not on `train_loss`

Comment: I've seen this done but I'm not sure that is correct because my loss implementation is different.

Comment: There is certainly a matter of scale in two-objective problems. Sometimes you need to manually select a weighting factor that trades-off between two objectives. But I don't think `len(dataset)` is particularly useful when you have `.mean()` on `elbo`.

Comment: I think that can be useful to divide `train_loss` by length of the dataset because I sum the loss at every for-loop. Otherwise, does it make sense to print `loss` for the last for-loop? Furthermore, does it make sense to print `math.exp(train_loss)` at the end? In this way I can obtain a loss that converge to zero.

Comment: You are using `train_loss` just for book-keeping, there is no role of it in the training process. So you can do anything you want with it - its not gonna alter the training dynamics in any way.
It does not make any sense alter the original loss value. Why exactly you want to see it go to zero ? Loss doesn't have to go to zero necessarily.

Comment: Because I read that KL admits solution between zero and infinity.

Comment: @InfT yes absolutely. KL is indeed greater than 0 - but its not true for log-likelihood. You have both of them.